# Merge changes of ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I have two `ObservableCollection<ClassA>`, CollectionA and CollectionB where

```
class ClassA
{
public int id { get; }
public string propA { get; set; }
private string PropB { get{return propA;} set{propA = value; NotifyPropertyChanged();} }
private ClassB propC { get; set; }
public ClassB PropC { get{return propC;} set{propC=value; NotifyPropertyChanged();} }
}
```

CollectionA contains 10 elements with random values as Properties and CollectionB is a deep copy of CollectionA.

How can I merge changes of CollectionB and its elements back into CollectionA and its element, so that NotifyPropertyChanged only gets raised for changed Properties?

EDIT: Entities get distinguished by an id.

Comment: Is any of the properties a unique identifier or would you need a full compare with all properties in order to distinguish entries?

Comment: I need a full compare and then merge only the changes of CollectionB into CollectionA to raise the appropriate NotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: So we are NOT talking about added / removed item but about same number of items and changed properties? I first misunderstood the question I guess.

Comment: actually both, so newly added items in CollectionB do also need to be added to CollectionA. I hope there is some reflection magic out there...

Comment: How do you distinguish between new items and changed items? Will the new items always come after the changed items and will there never be removed items?

Comment: I clarifyed the Question.

Comment: Another question: Does the order of items matter and is it possible for item order to change / for new items not to be at the end of `CollectionB`? Also, instead of conditionally  setting properties, the property `set` should compare current value to new value and conditionally raise the changed event. This way you don't have to write an external comparison logic before updating properties.

Comment: order does not matter, background is that im constantly pulling a list of objects from a rest api and need the changes in a different observablelist that is bind to gui elements. i could check for changes in the properties setter but then i would still need a way to assign every propertie from the rest list to gui list